# Why do I need to create Mutiple SSPs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Why do I need to create Multiple SSPs in MOSS?

My manager (sharepoint administrator) asked me to create another SSP which he wanted to use for TOP Management users. He didnt tell me what was the reason for it.

I was wondering what all scenarios we need to create Multiple SSPs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very vague question, please add more info!

And as a general answer, **you don't need to**, the concept is to share the services under the SSP between multiple web applications, what scenario do you have to need to create more than one?

Edit after question update:

```
 An SSP host the services that will be used ( consumed ) by any associated Web applications. These services include :
    Profiles
    Audiences
    Business Data Catalog Connections
    Search and Indexing
    Single Sign On
    Excel Services
    Usage Reporting
```

[Source](http://msmvps.com/blogs/obts/archive/2006/11/03/242608.aspx)

So if your manager won't actually have something special on any of those services, I don't see a reason to do it. We had a customer once that needed the entire mysite and profiles customized, so we created a SSP just for that one web application.